# Xquery to get the value of a specific element from an XML which is stored as [XML Nullable column] in DB2

Tags: java, xml, db2, xquery-sql

Consider the following XML :

```
     <Employee>
        <EmpDetails>   
             <Name>huff</Name>
        </EmpDetails>
     </Employee>
```

Above XMLis stored as a `column(DATA)` with data type `[XML NULLABLE]` in a table in DB2.
Assume that the structure of the table is something like this:

```
      Table name:  REGEVENT
     Columns are: REFID (VARCHAR), APPID(VARCHAR), DATA(XML NULLABLE)
```

Suppose the value in the table is: `REFID(12345)`, `APPID(54321)`, DATA(Employee xml as mentioned above).

Now I have to get the value of element  in the XML stored in column DATA using Xquery (Or any other way is also fine).

I am trying the following query, but I am getting the value EmpName as NULL.

```
select XMLCAST(XMLQUERY('$d/Employee/EmpDetails/Name' PASSING rg.DATA AS "d") AS VARCHAR(50)) AS EmpName from REGEVENT  rg where REFID='12345';
```

Comment: http://amolnpujari.wordpress.com/2008/04/12/db2-native-xml/ might help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not get the value using the XQUERY but instead first, I got the value of column 'DATA' as String and then used the following method (which uses Xpath) to get the value of the node 'Name'.

public String getEmpNameFromEmployee(String employeeXml)

```
  throws SAXException, IOException, XPathExpressionException {
    DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
            .newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder = null;
    try {
        builder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Document xmlDocument = builder.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(employeeXml
            .getBytes()));
    XPath xPath = (XPath) XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
    String expression = "/Employee/EmpDetails/Name";
    String empName = xPath.compile(expression).evaluate(
            xmlDocument);
    return empName;
```